# Star rating and microformats

Tags: image, algorithm, rating-system, microformats

I have a star rating on my website and I'm trying to use microformats. I read the Google's documentation and they give as an example :

```
<span class="review hreview-aggregate">
  Note globale : <span class="rating">4,4</span> basée sur <span class="count">89
  </span> avis
```

Sorry for the French words.
Now what am I supposed if I'm not showing numbers but stars on the website?
Thanks

Comment: the "type" doesn't matter for hreview-aggregate, as long as they are integers. bonus: here's a jsfiddle with semantic markup and styled already for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/jUbka/

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> the "type" doesn't matter for hreview-aggregate, as long as they are integers

The spec says:

> fixed point integer [1.0-5.0], with optional alternate worst (default:1.0) and/or best (default:5.0), also fixed point integers, and explicit average.
>
> Optionally a different integral "worst" value and/or "best" value may be specified to indicate a different range (e.g. 6 from 0-10).

**References**

- [hReview-aggregate 0.2 · Microformats Wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview-aggregate)
- [hReview - a Handy Implementation Guide for Your Review Pages](https://builtvisible.com/using-hreview-microformat-on-your-review-page/)
- [Marking Up Your Site with Structured Data - Bing Webmaster Tools](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731)
- [What are microformats?](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/microformats/what-is-microformat.xml)